# Get a line from a file and add as a column into another file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have two files.

File A:

```
Unix
```

File B:

```
A,B 
C,D
E,f
.,.
.,.
N,N
```

Expected Output:

```
A,B,Unix  
C,D,Unix
E,f,Unix
.,.,Unix
.,.,Unix
N,N,Unix
```

How it is possible with in Linux shell script?

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: Are the numbers part of `FileB` or just present?

Comment: No , Actually I have added number for getting column display here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
➜ cat a
A,B
C,D
E,f
.,.
.,.
N,N
➜ cat f2
Unix
➜ awk 'BEGIN{getline f2<"f2"}; {printf("%s,%s\n",$0,f2);}' a
A,B,Unix
C,D,Unix
E,f,Unix
.,.,Unix
.,.,Unix
N,N,Unix
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `fileA` contains only 1 word, it's better to pass it to `awk` as a parameter.

```
awk -v v="Unix" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$(NF+1)=v}1' fileB
```

If this `fileA` contains more words, and assuming there is only 1 per line, you could also use this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==FNR{a[++i]=$1;next} {for(j=1; j<=i; j++) $(NF+1)=a[j]}1' fileA fileB
```

Answer (score 0):

And then there is good old `paste` as an option:

```
$  cat file1
UNIX
$  cat file2
A,B
C,D
E,F
$ paste -d',' file2 <(yes `cat file1` | head -n $(cat file2 | wc -l))
A,B,UNIX
C,D,UNIX
E,F,UNIX
```

The tricky part here is that the number of rows differ in `file1` and `file2`, so we need to repeat the `UNIX` row of `file1` as often as necessary (i.e, as many times as there are rows in `file2`) to be able to use `paste`.